# how to add two different numbers in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have this array [3, 5, -4, 8, 11, 1, -1, 6] and I'm trying to add each number inside it so that the sum of the two numbers is equal to 10, but so far it can only add the same number to itself and not two different numbers. How can I do this with javascript?

in this array for example the function should return [-1, 11]

my function

```js
function sum(array) {
    let result = 10;
    let newArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] + array[i] === result) {
            newArray.push(array[i], array[i]);
        }
    }

    return newArray;
}

let array = [3, 5, -4, 8, 11, 1, -1, 6];
console.log(sum(array));
```

Comment: Please share the code you already have so we can help

Comment: To clarify: you're searching the array for a _pair_ of numbers that sum to 10...?

Comment: Please always try to share your atempt.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+match+two+integers+from+array+giving+sum+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```js
function sum(array) {
  let result = 10;
  let newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
      if (array[i] + array[x] === result) {
        if (array[i] !== array[x]) {
          newArray.push(array[i], array[x]);
          return newArray;
        }

      }
    }
  }
}

let array = [3, 5, -4, 8, 11, 1, -1, 6];
console.log(sum(array));
```